# HttpListener Access Denied

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-7, uac, httplistener, netsh

I am writing an HTTP server in C#.

When I try to execute the function `HttpListener.Start()` I get an `HttpListenerException` saying

> "Access Denied".

When I run the app in admin mode in windows 7 it works fine.

Can I make it run without admin mode? if yes how?
If not how can I make the app change to admin mode after start running?

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private HttpListener httpListener = null;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.Server();
        }

        public void Server()
        {
            this.httpListener = new HttpListener();

            if (httpListener.IsListening)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Server is currently running.");

            httpListener.Prefixes.Clear();
            httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:4444/");

            try
            {
                httpListener.Start(); //Throws Exception
            }
            catch (HttpListenerException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Message.Contains("Access is denied"))
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If someone want to avoid that error he can try writing it with TcpListener. It doesn't require admin privileges

Comment: I face the same issue, in Visual Studio 2008 + Windows 7, it produce 'Access denied' error, to counter solve this is to run the Visual Studio 2008 in Admin Mode

Comment: What is this madness? I've never seen these hoops opening a non-privileged port in any other language, on any operating system. I don't even know what they're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 360, accepted):

Yes you can run HttpListener in non-admin mode.  All you need to do is grant permissions to the particular URL.  e.g.

```sh
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user
```

Documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx).

Comment: This is helpful, but for completeness, the URL specified in this line of code: `httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:4444/");` must match EXACTLY with the one in the `netsh` command.  For example, I had `httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:80/");` and the same `netsh` command you have, and the HttpListenerException will still be thrown.  I needed to change `httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:80/");`Thanks for your help @Darrel Miller, because you got me on the right path to figuring this out!

Comment: And don't forget the trailing slash if "MyUri" is empty, otherwise you'll get a `The parameter is incorrect` error. Example: `url=http://+:80/`

Comment: Is there any way to do this for a non-administrative user, even for `http://localhost:80/`? I have a desktop application that needs to receive one request on such a URL, and it seems a shame to require that an administrator install it on 50 desktops, just for this one purpose.

Comment: Apparently not.  There's also no mention of elevation or administrative privileges being required in the documentation page.  So it's easy to assume that this will act as a "smarter" TCPListener, when in reality there is MAJOR reason not to use it - yet this isn't documented.

Comment: @DavidFord  There are workarounds https://leastprivilege.com/2007/03/23/punching-holes-into-http-sys/  The other option is to use Kestrel because it doesn't use http.sys

Comment: @DarrelMiller - thanks for the thoughts, however the key point I'm making here is that Microsoft's documentation on this topic does -not- indicate the major issues and headaches deploying any code written using HTTP.sys.  I've written considerable software, as well as making assumptions that just "listening on a port" would be a trivial exercise (as it is in the raw sockets API's).  This ended up being completely wasted effort as the code can't be deployed without elevation.  A switch to Kestrel is non-trivial.

Comment: @DavidFord  I do agree it is a real pain.  And very unfortunate that the MSDN docs make no mention of it.  Unfortunately, limiting malware from opening local servers is a necessary evil.  Based on your comment about the switch to Kestrel being non-trivial, might I suggest future efforts are based on the OWIN abstraction.  That makes switching hosts much easier.

Comment: @DavidFord I'm running into same issue! All I can think to do is create a separate .bat script to setup the netsh ports necessary for the app to run. Such a script would only need to be executed once by a sysadmin (say, at installation time if your .MSI foo is strong). From my experience, it's a system setting that survives restarts and can be applied globally (to all users).

Comment: Running netsh requires admin ;(

Comment: Quick way to just make this work without knowing much else is to set the domain to Everyone and Host to '+': netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8282/ user=Everyone listen=yes

Comment: @DarrelMiller this doesn't stop malware from opening local servers. You can still create an HTTP server, you just can't do it using HTTP.sys or `HttpListener`, e.g. one can call `TcpListener.Create(4444).Start()` and implement HTTP/1.1 over it. So I don't see why this (seemingly undocumented) permission check exists.

Answer (score 35):

If you use `http://localhost:80/` as a prefix, you can listen to http requests with no need for Administrative privileges.

Comment: Can you post some example code? I just tried this with `http://localhost:80/` and got an "Access Denied".

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't seem to work. Please check if you're running as administrator, which shouldn't be the normal case.

Comment: if this would work, i would consider it a windows bug. no matter what you think about windows, i assume this to be of a very basic level that very, very likely they did not miss to handle correctly.

Comment: So more than 2 years later, this works for me now on Windows Server 2008 R2 with .NET framework 4.5. `httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:4444/");` indeed shows an `Access Denied` error but `httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:4444/");` work without any problem. It looks like Microsoft excluded `localhost` from these restrictions. Interestingly, `httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:4444/");` still shows an Access Denied error, so the only thing that works is `localhost:{any port}`

Comment: @Tony thanks your comment was actually the most valuable for me. I had "127.0.0.1" in several configs.  QA reported that it wasn't working on Windows 8.1 but was in Windows 10 just fine (and I tested it myself in Win10).  Oddly, it seems Microsoft has Everyone granted to use 127.0.0.1 in Win10 but not 8.1 (and presumably prior versions), but sure enough, localhost is fine.  Thanks

Comment: @Tony ah shit, it requires that host header now though :(, so browsing to http://127.0.0.1 from a browser.  This is a problem since I need to expose it externally from a dumb TCP proxy with no knowledge of host headers.

Comment: Also, doesn't work for me if I try "localhost" instead of "+" in netsh add urlacl command... apparently the urlacl junk is not consistent with httplistener.

Comment: @Tony http://127.0.0.1:4444/  seems to work for 127 and localhost at the same time.   If you listen only on localhost then the 127 does not work.   same behavior with your PcName vs your ip address.   A specific IP seems to allow name and ip.

Comment: @Tony I confirm that your solution works on Windows 10. Imo, this is a much better solution than running netsh to grant privileged.

Answer (score 31):

> Can I make it run without admin mode? if yes how? If not how can I make the app change to admin mode after start running?

You can't, it has to start with elevated privileges. You can restart it with the `runas` verb, which will prompt the user to switch to admin mode

```
static void RestartAsAdmin()
{
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("yourApp.exe") { Verb = "runas" };
    Process.Start(startInfo);
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

---

EDIT: actually, that's not true; HttpListener can run without elevated privileges, but you need to give permission for the URL on which you want to listen. See [Darrel Miller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4115328/98713) for details.

Comment: Can you please explain why I have to start with elevated privileges?

Comment: You also need to add this line 'startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;' before 'Process.Start(startInfo);'

Comment: @Randall: because that's how Windows works... a process can't switch to admin mode while it's running. Regarding UseShellExecute: it depends on what you're executing. I tested my code with "notepad.exe", it works fine without UseShellExecute = false

Comment: Thanks. About the UseShellExecute: I tried to run the code I posted. Another problem is that for some reason it asked me once if I want to run as administrator and any other time after that it doesn't ask. I restarted, Debugged to make sure it goes there and nothing. any suggestions?

Comment: Not really... perhaps the second time you were already running it as admin ?

Comment: I decided to try and disable the 'startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;' and it worked perfectly. Thank you very very much :)

Comment: @Thomas  There is no problem running HttpListener in non-admin mode.

Answer (score 27):

The syntax was wrong for me, you must include the quotes:

```
netsh http add urlacl url="http://+:4200/" user=everyone
```

otherwise I received "The parameter is incorrect"

Comment: "The parameter is incorrect" can also be returned if you do not specify a trailing `/` on the url

Answer (score 18):

As an alternative that doesn't require elevation or netsh you could also use TcpListener for instance.

The following is a modified excerpt of this sample:
https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows/tree/master/OAuthDesktopApp

```
// Generates state and PKCE values.
string state = randomDataBase64url(32);
string code_verifier = randomDataBase64url(32);
string code_challenge = base64urlencodeNoPadding(sha256(code_verifier));
const string code_challenge_method = "S256";

// Creates a redirect URI using an available port on the loopback address.
var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 0);
listener.Start();
string redirectURI = string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/", IPAddress.Loopback, ((IPEndPoint)listener.LocalEndpoint).Port);
output("redirect URI: " + redirectURI);

// Creates the OAuth 2.0 authorization request.
string authorizationRequest = string.Format("{0}?response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile&redirect_uri={1}&client_id={2}&state={3}&code_challenge={4}&code_challenge_method={5}",
    authorizationEndpoint,
    System.Uri.EscapeDataString(redirectURI),
    clientID,
    state,
    code_challenge,
    code_challenge_method);

// Opens request in the browser.
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(authorizationRequest);

// Waits for the OAuth authorization response.
var client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

// Read response.
var response = ReadString(client);

// Brings this app back to the foreground.
this.Activate();

// Sends an HTTP response to the browser.
WriteStringAsync(client, "<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='10;url=https://google.com'></head><body>Please close this window and return to the app.</body></html>").ContinueWith(t =>
{
    client.Dispose();
    listener.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("HTTP server stopped.");
});

// TODO: Check the response here to get the authorization code and verify the code challenge
```

The read and write methods being:

```
private string ReadString(TcpClient client)
{
    var readBuffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
    string fullServerReply = null;

    using (var inStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var stream = client.GetStream();

        while (stream.DataAvailable)
        {
            var numberOfBytesRead = stream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
            if (numberOfBytesRead <= 0)
                break;

            inStream.Write(readBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead);
        }

        fullServerReply = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inStream.ToArray());
    }

    return fullServerReply;
}

private Task WriteStringAsync(TcpClient client, string str)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream(), new UTF8Encoding(false)))
        {
            writer.Write("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
            writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            writer.Write("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
            writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            writer.Write("Content-Length: " + str.Length);
            writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            writer.Write(str);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This was really useful as we had the HttpListener issue when implementing an IBrowser for the IdentityModel.OidcClient library so a very similar use case to the above.

Comment: It's worth noting that the code above has bugs in it though. Firstly using a StreamWriter with UTF8 causes issues in some browsers, I'm guessing because of a BOM being output or something like that. I changed it to ASCII and all is well.
I also added some code to wait for data to become available for read on the stream as it would sometimes return no data.

Comment: Thanks @mackie - that part was taken directly from Microsoft's own sample actually. I guess they didn't really test it properly. If you can edit my answer go ahead and fix the methods - otherwise maybe send me the changes and I can update it.

Comment: Instead of using ASCII one should use the following constructor ```new UTF8Encoding(false)```, that disables emitting of a BOM. I've changed this already in the answer

Comment: I prefer this solution over the accepted answer. Running netsh seems like a hack. This is a solid programmatic solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

In case you want to use the flag "user=Everyone" you need to adjust it to your system language. In english it is as mentioned:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/ user=Everyone
```

In german it would be:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/ user=Jeder
```

Comment: In spanish-language systems, do: user=Todos

Comment: Plus, I needed to put the URL in quotes, as mentioned in another answer.

Comment: In Polish user=wszyscy

Answer (score 9):

By default Windows defines the following prefix that is available to everyone:
http://+:80/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/

So you can register your `HttpListener` via:

`Prefixes.Add("http://+:80/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D") + "/";`

This sometimes causes problems with software such as Skype which will try to utilise port 80 by default.

Comment: Skype was the culprit. I changed the port to **not** be 80 and it worked.

Answer (score 8):

You can start your application as administrator if you add Application Manifest to your project.

Just Add New Item to your project and select "Application Manifest File". Change the `<requestedExecutionLevel>` element to:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Answer (score 8):

```
httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:4444/");
```

you use "*" so you execute following cmd as admin

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:4444/ user=username
```

no use +, must use *, because you spec *:4444~.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx

Comment: This was it for me.  It worked for me to `.Add("http://+:9000/")`

Answer (score 3):

I also faced similar problem.If you have already reserved url then you have to first delete the url to run in non admin mode else it will fail with Access is Denied error.

```
netsh http delete urlacl url=http://+:80
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all,
it was of great help.
Just to add more [from MS page]:

> **Warning**
>
> Top-level wildcard bindings (`http://*:8080/` and `http://+:8080`) should not be used. Top-level wildcard bindings can open up your app to security vulnerabilities. This applies to both strong and weak wildcards. Use explicit host names rather than wildcards. Subdomain wildcard binding (for example, `*.mysub.com`) doesn't have this security risk if you control the entire parent domain (as opposed to `*.com`, which is vulnerable). See rfc7230 section-5.4 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, for some reasons probably linked with HTTPS and certificates, the native .NET HttpListener requires admin privileges, and even for HTTP only protocol...

**The good point**

It is interesting to note that HTTP protocol is on top of TCP protocol, but launching a C# TCP listener doesn't require any admin privileges to run. In other words, it is conceptually possible to implement an HTTP server which do not requires admin privileges.

**Alternative**

Below, an example of project which doesn't require admin privileges:
https://github.com/EmilianoElMariachi/ElMariachi.Http.Server