# HttpListenerException "access denied" for non-admins

Tags: c#, exception, httplistener, non-admin

I have written a C# application that uses `HttpListener` to listen for HTTP requests -obviously! The namespace prefix I use is also registered using `netsh` for the current user (as suggested by everyone on SO).

The problem is despite using netsh my application still throws an "access is denied" exception for non-admin users. The OS is Windows 7.

Update: It appears as though my application is not executing the `netsh` command when I run it with a non-admin user. Is there any problems with my code? There are no exceptions thrown.

```
    AddAddress("http://localhost:8400/", Environment.UserDomainName, Environment.UserName);

    HttpListener _listener = new HttpListener();
    _listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8400/");
    _listener.Start();

    ...

    /** method stolen from an SO thread. sorry can't remember the author **/
    static void AddAddress(string address, string domain, string user)
    {
        string args = string.Format(@"http add urlacl url={0}", address) + " user=\"" + domain + "\\" + user + "\"";

        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("netsh", args);
        psi.Verb = "runas";
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        psi.UseShellExecute = true;

        Process.Start(psi).WaitForExit();
    }
```

Comment: This is *likely* due to Windows 7 disallowing a usermode application from creating a listener on port 80 (which is default for HTTP).  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4115328/507793

Comment: Thanks. I am not using port 80. I also just posted my code.

Comment: I suspect that your `netsh` is failing to add the mapping that you want. Or perhaps it's because you're using `locolhast` rather than `localhost`. Or is that just a typo in your question?

Comment: SO editor wouldn't let me type localhost, so I had to change it! Also when I run the same netsh command in the command prompt I get a message saying that the namespace is already registered. So I assume netsh was successful.

Comment: Enter `netsh http show urlacl` at the command prompt, and find the entry you made. Be sure that Listen is Yes. As I recall, you have to add "listen=true" after the user name.

Comment: I don't understand this. When I run your command I don't see my non-admin user listed anywhere. But running the "netsh http add" command shows: Cannot create a file when that file already exists. Here's what I run in the command prompt: netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost:8400/ user="mycomp-01\standard user"

Comment: So apparently you can only reserve a namespace for 1 user at a time. But this is a problem because I need to add more than 1 user. Is there a way?!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The line that I use when I'm doing an HttpListener is:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8008/ user=Everyone listen=yes
```

The user can be an individual user or a user group. So if you want only Administrators to have access, for example:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8008/ user=Administrators listen=yes
```

You can get help on the command:

```
netsh http add urlacl help
```

Note that the `url=` is optional. Also, older versions of the command require true or false for the listen parameter. Current versions use yes or no.

Comment: Well, user groups are not available on all Windows platforms according to here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-vista/User-groups-in-Windows. BUT, looks like user=Everyone did it!!! But where was this documented?!!!! I wasted 2 days on this! Is there a similar thing for httpcfg (for Win XP)? Thanks!

Comment: @user1936026: I'm not familiar with httpcfg, but if I had to work with it, I'd probably start with the examples at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786389(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: According to the help, listen takes a yes|no value not true|false. It wouldn't work for me with the listen=true.

Comment: @tafoo85: Older versions of Windows used true/false. Newer versions use yes/no. Or perhaps it was the other way around. Glad you found the fix.

Comment: @JimMischel: I'm trying this in a command prompt on a normal, non-admin Windows account. I keep getting  error type 5, and it's telling me to run as admin. Do you know if it's possible for a non-admin user to successfully execute this command?

Comment: @CharlieSalts: To my knowledge, it is not possible for a non-admin to execute this command successfully.

Comment: @JimMischel: Thanks. I guess I'll have to roll my own.

Comment: @CharlieSalts: The command must run under an admin-account to grant access to the listener for non-admins. Once the access is granted, no admin needs to be involved anymore.

Comment: @Davatar: Thanks. Asking our customers to run the program under an  admin account, even once, was not possible. I ended up writing my own small http server, and it works for what we need.

Comment: I realize this is an old post - but someone else might benefit. It sounds like your clients need to run a local application. Does installing the application not involve an Admin? you might have an opportunity to incorporate the netsh command into the installation process, and getting what you want.