# HttpListener Access is Denied - Effect on install?

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-web-api, httplistener

So I know this is covered everywhere a million times.. iv seen ten SO posts, and iv barely looked. The fix for getting an Access is denied error from HttpListener, is to run the netsh urlacl command.

See here: [HttpListener Access Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019466/httplistener-access-denied), here: [HttpListenerException “access denied” for non-admins [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962334/httplistenerexception-access-denied-for-non-admins) etc etc..

What is the best way to fix this for installation of a program?

Is the program still going to suffer this problem if it is installed?

Struggling to see how this problem is going to impact the end install result, just trying to get some help with it!

**EDIT:**
Following a comment,here is some background info: my app provides a WebAPI end point for data access for testing our other code. I ran into this problem, and wonder if an Installer would mean I could bypass the problem altogether, or whether I would need to handle it in the installer.

Comment: It depends on what your program does exactly... You need to give more information.

Comment: If your app is run as a non-admin then this will happen.  If your app runs in an admin context its not a problem, if it does not you need to add the url acl as indicated.

Comment: @AlexK. This is quite annoying, the answer I was sort of hoping was that because the files etc were installed, rather than placed. They would be treated differently by the OS. (I was sort of expecting as part of that, that there could be some registration of URL). This is frustrating :(

Comment: @PatrickHofman I have added some background info, sounds like its still going to be an issue though no matter what I do.