# Why does HttpListener ignore external requests?

Tags: c#, .net, tcplistener, httplistener

My computer is behind a router that forwards port 80 to it (as port 80).  My problem is that HttpListener appears to ignore requests addressed to the external IP address.

The problem is not with the router; if I create a blank C# console project and add only the following lines of code:

```
System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener s = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 80);
s.Start();
System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient c = s.AcceptTcpClient();
```

...and run the program [note: the first time this program is run, the user may have to allow a firewall exception], it will terminate if I navigate to

```
http://localhost/testpath/
```

in my browser OR if I navigate to

```
http://externalipaddress/testpath/
```

in my browser -- either address successfully attempts a port 80 connection.  So, everything is set up properly -- this computer can accept internal and external connections on port 80.

Now, if I create another blank C# console project and add only the following lines of code:

```
System.Net.HttpListener s = new System.Net.HttpListener();
s.Prefixes.Add("http://+:80/testpath/");
s.Start();
System.Net.HttpListenerContext c = s.GetContext();
```

...first, I'll get a HttpListenerException saying Access is denied because of the issues mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019466/httplistener-access-denied-c-sharp-windows-7).  Then it will run properly when I close Visual Studio and reopen it as Administrator.  The program will terminate (properly) when I navigate to

```
http://localhost/testpath/
```

However, my request simply times out if I navigate to

```
http://externalipaddress/testpath/
```

**Why does my external request to HttpListener time out?**  The result is reproducible with a numeric IP address or domain name for 'externalipaddress', as well as many permutations of subfolders, slashes, etc, and also for the prefixes "http://*:80/testpath/", "http: //externaldomain:80/testpath/", and "http: //externalipaddress:80/testpath/" (no spaces; added for stackoverflow formatting).

Comment: Have you asked your ISP if they block incoming connections on port 80? It's uncommon but some do. Also try to resolve your external IP so that it points to `homeusr51363_516.your_isp.com` or similar

Comment: If my ISP blocked incoming connections, how would the success of the first code (which connects to port 80 via the external IP address) be explained?  As noted, I've tried using a numeric IP address and a resolvable domain name in the browser requests.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out the Windows firewall was silently eating the incoming port 80 requests from outside of localhost.  When I disabled the firewall, the HttpListener detected the external requests.  When I re-enabled the firewall, the HttpListener stopped detecting the external requests.  When I enabled the disabled Inbound Rule entitled "BranchCache Content Retrieval (HTTP-In)" which allows the SYSTEM program (which hosts the service that does the TCP listening for HttpListener) to listen on port 80, the HttpListener again detected the external requests.

To find the Inbound Rules list on Windows 7, Start -> Control Panel -> System and Security -> Windows Firewall -> Advanced Settings -> Inbound Rules.

Comment: This is a big issue. I'm reluctant to add a firewall exception for the port I'm using. IMHO this is a bad practice. Is there still no solution about that ?

Comment: By the definition of a firewall, there must be a firewall exception for the port you want to use.  The difficulty here was that HttpListener uses something outside your program to listen on port 80, so simply allowing a firewall exception for your program is not sufficient for HttpListener to be allowed to listen for connections.

Comment: Thank you Ben, you helped me to understand the issue. It look like to me that this is still a security issue, but since there is no other solution, I'll follow your advice.

Comment: Just had a problem with HttpListener, it's now 2024. The rule mentioned in the answer only influences port 80, I was using HttpListener with a custom port. I had to add a firewall rule for the SYSTEM process to allow incoming TCP connections at the port I wanted. It appears HttpListener is a .NET wrapper to interact with some native service running under the System process.