# SignalR at url = 127.1.1.0 access denied

Tags: c#, signalr

Simple i have host the server in Console Application and i used  127.1.1.0 instead of localhost. 
Yeah i know if i use localhost then its will work fine..

But  i want to know why on 127.1.1.0 its not work??

Its not work if i use local IP like 198.xxx.xx.xx.  Why?

Its not work if i use Server live IP  and run this console on Server pc , server live ip like 203.xxx.xx.xx.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SignalR.Hosting.Self;
using SignalR.Hubs;

namespace SignalRhost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "http://127.0.0.1:8081/";

            var server = new Server(url);
            server.MapHubs();

            server.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("SignalR server started at " + url);
```

I get error . access Denied on server.start() method.

Please explain why its not work??
 if i can't use server live ip then how can i run console on live server for test with client :OL?

Thanks Advance .

Comment: possible duplicate of [HttpListener Access Denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019466/httplistener-access-denied) - either of the top 2 answers should help

Comment: Can you tell me.i publish my console application for run its easy on other pc for test... how can i make my application to run as a administrator  privileges

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2818776/1901857)

Comment: Please tell me also . If client is behind Proxy ,firewall and firewall of client pc preventing some protocol like icmp or other port..then client is able to communicate with server ???

Comment: That's something you have to try and test - if you need help you might be able to ask on http://superuser.com/

Comment: Thanks for the Quick Help Rhumbor . Again Thanks