# URL mismatch while authenticating google AnalyticsService

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, google-analytics

I have asp.net mvc project hosted on windows azure, i am using google analytic service and its authenticating properly on my localhost however on hosted server it does not work. it gives me this error "the redirect URI in the request, callback, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client"

My hosted URL is "http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/" and the callback url i am giving in google console is "http://ispycms.azurewebsites.net/Dashboard/Index"

Below is the C# code for authenticating to google analytic, note that i am using service instance to make request, i have placed this code in Index method of Controller Dashboard.

```
    [SessionExpireFilter]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {                
            var result = new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppAuthFlowMetadata()).
                    AuthorizeAsync(CancellationToken.None);

            if (result.Result.Credential != null)
            {
                service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = result.Result.Credential,
                    ApplicationName = "iSPY Stats"
                });                    
            }

//Request data 
            // make a request
        var request = service.Data.Ga.Get(
            "ga:" + profileId,
            "2016-01-01",
            "2016-05-05",
            "ga:totalEvents");
        request.Dimensions = "ga:eventCategory,ga:eventAction,ga:eventLabel,ga:date,ga:hour,ga:minute";
        request.Filters = "ga:eventCategory==Pack;ga:eventAction==Open";

        // run the request and get the data
        return request.Execute();
```

Comment: Check the error message it should give you the url you are calling from. You can use that in redirect uri.

Comment: The redirect URI in the request, https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/google/callback, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. Visit https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/1016684719145-d4khidqovk6oano8dktdk2mnqrooprg1.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=1016684719145 to update the authorized redirect URIs

Comment: then set google developer console redirect uri to mysite.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/google/callback

Comment: thanks @DaImTo .... its working now.. however i am facing another issue .. i am getting access denied error " System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is denied"    .. below is snippet of stack trace. ..                                                 [HttpListenerException (0x5): Access is denied]
   System.Net.HttpListener.SetupV2Config() +333
   System.Net.HttpListener.Start() +297   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.<ReceiveCodeAsync>d__6.MoveNext() +188

Comment: that's something in azure I think.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019466/httplistener-access-denied