# Windows netsh "+" wildcard not working for ServiceHost

Tags: c#, wcf, http, netsh, servicehost

*Disclaimer: Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4019466/2628257), this one is specific to the most voted comment from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4115328/2628257)*

I use a ServiceHost object to create a HTTP service: http://{IP}:80/myService

My application runs from a non-admin account (and this must be kept like this). From several sources I found that the solution was calling the following from an administrator cmd prompt:

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/myService/ user=Everyone`

This does not work, I still get an exception regarding access:

```
System.ServiceModel.AddressAccessDeniedException: HTTP could not register URL http://127.0.0.1:80/myService/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details). ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is denied
   at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()
   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnOpen()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnOpen()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManager.Open(TransportChannelListener channelListener)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManagerContainer.Open(SelectTransportManagersCallback selectTransportManagerCallback)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open()
```

However if I call this line, it works:

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://127.0.0.1:80/myService/ user=Everyone`

Note I explicitely specified the IP. I don't know the IP that the user will be using, so I need the + wildcard to work. I cannot figure out why it is not working and I cannot find a workaround to this.

- Runnin as administrator is not a solution.
- Found info on the [UrlPrefix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364698(v=vs.85).aspx) wildcards from Microsoft but still not clear

Comment: Does adding `listen=yes` to the end of your command change anything?

Comment: listen=yes is the default, I also tried delegate=yes but it has no effect

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this exact scenario as well. So far, I suspect that the behaviour actually varies based on the version of Windows. Windows 10 seems to treat URL reservations on the loopback IP (`127.0.0.1`) a bit differently -- everything else seems to work as expected though.

On my Windows 10 machine, I'm seeing the same thing you are -- if I have a reservation with a strong wildcard (ie, `http://+:80/`), registering a URL prefix tied to the local loopback fails every time. This is *not* the case on Windows Server 2008 or 2012, however; it works fine there.

I'm sure this is related, but I have actually had success registering URLs on the local loopback on Windows 10 without *any* prior reservation on that port for that user (and without being admin), which is a bit strange given that I can't find any documentation pointing to this being possible. Below is the output of a call to `netsh http show servicestate` which one such reservation:

```
Server session ID: E700000120000035
Version: 2.0
State: Active
Properties:
    Max bandwidth: 4294967295
    Timeouts:
        Entity body timeout (secs): 120
        Drain entity body timeout (secs): 120
        Request queue timeout (secs): 120
        Idle connection timeout (secs): 120
        Header wait timeout (secs): 120
        Minimum send rate (bytes/sec): 150
URL groups:
URL group ID: DF00000140000004
    State: Active
    Request queue name: Request queue is unnamed.
    Properties:
        Max bandwidth: inherited
        Max connections: inherited
        Timeouts:
            Timeout values inherited
        Number of registered URLs: 1
        Registered URLs:
            HTTP://127.0.0.1:8081:127.0.0.1/
```

Note that strange prefix format (`HTTP://127.0.0.1:8081:127.0.0.1/`) -- that is not what I passed to the ServiceHost (I just specified `http://127.0.0.1:8081`). I suspect that Microsoft at some point introduced the ability to make 'special' URL registrations on the local loopback without prior reservation via `netsh`.

This is pure speculation on my part, but I suspect that these special reservations also come with the caveat that the underlying socket in `http.sys` only binds to local loopback for security purposes. This would obviously clash with any other process that would like to handle requests on that port which would fit under the `http://+:80/` reservation, which could include remote requests coming in on a different interface.