# HttpListener access denied, how to solve without using a command line

Tags: c#, websocket, .net-core, httplistener

I found really interestic topic here: [HttpListener Access Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019466/httplistener-access-denied).

What I'm trying to do is creating Websocket application with my own http server. This app is based on .net core 2.0 and it should work on each operating system (windows, linux, ios) so I would like to avoid using the command line. Manifest file to elevate privileges is poor solution also.

This app should work on specified port, not only at 80.

I really don't believe that there is no any solution for this. I try to convert HttpListener to TcpListener, but this class has not Context.IsWebsocketRequest variable so I will be forced to handle websocket connection on my own (I want avoid this too).

Is there a way to bypass this problem using code only?

Comment: You can bind localhost without any permissions, but any externally visible binding requires the program to be run as admin or have a url acl in windows.

Comment: On linux, binding to ports below 1024 typically requires root permissions.

Comment: Ok so can you provide me equivalent of netsh register url command for linux and ios? I basically don't work on those systems so any help will be appreciated. Then I will be able to start process with those commands based on os