Unhandled exception. System.Net.HttpListenerException (5): Access is denied
I'm learning the basics of using the HttpListener class in C# to create a web server,
but the problem is that it keeps not allowing access and leaves this error. Can you please take a look and help me fix it?
My bug:

Unhandled exception. System.Net.HttpListenerException (5): Access is
denied.    at System.Net.HttpListener.AddPrefixCore(String
registeredPrefix)      at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()
at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()    at
C_coban.httpListener.Main(String[] args) in
C:\Users\thehz\OneDrive\Desktop\C#coban\httpListener.cs:line 30    at
C_coban.httpListener.(String[] args)

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

namespace C_coban
{
public class httpListener
{
static async Task Main(string\[\] args){
if(HttpListener.IsSupported){
Console.WriteLine("support");
}
else {
Console.WriteLine("Not sp");
throw new Exception("Not sp");
}

         var server =new HttpListener();
    
         server.Prefixes.Add("http://+:8080/");
    
         server.Start();
    
         Console.WriteLine("server http start ");
    
    
         do {
            var context =await server.GetContextAsync(); 
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected ");
    
            var response =context.Response;
            var outputStream =response.OutputStream;
               
            response.Headers.Add("content-type","text/html");
    
            var html =" <h1>hello world</h1>";
          
            var bytes =Encoding .UTF8.GetBytes(html);
            await outputStream.WriteAsync(bytes,0,bytes.Length);   
            outputStream.Close();
         }while(server.IsListening);
    
        }
    }

I want to understand why I can't access it and learn from it in the future.

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019466/httplistener-access-denied

did you tried different port. For example '8888'
